# How to find and rank all prefixes in a list of strings?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, prefix, trie

I have a list of strings and I want to find popular prefixes. The prefixes are special in that they occur as strings in the input list.

I found a similar question here but the answers are geared to find **the one** most common prefix:
[Find *most* common prefix of strings - a better way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628428/find-most-common-prefix-of-strings-a-better-way)

While my problem is similar, it differs in that I need to find all popular prefixes. Or to maybe state it a little simplistically, rank prefixes from most common to least.

As an example, consider the following list of strings:
in, india, indian, indian flag, bull, bully, bullshit

Prefixes rank:
in - 4 times
india - 3 times
bull - 3 times
...and so on. Please note - in, bull, india are all present in the input list.

The following are not valid prefixes:
ind
bu
bul
...since they do not occur in the input list.

What data structure should I be looking at to model my solution? I'm inclined to use a "trie" with a counter on each node that tracks how many times has that node been touched during the creation of the trie.

All suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

p.s. - I love python and would love if someone could post a quick snippet that could get me started.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: this is actually a duplicate of the question you linked .... `Counter_Instance.most_common(10)` would give you the 10 most common for instance

Comment: Honest admission, it was just on paper until now. Don't have any code to show. Taking note for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
words = [ "in", "india", "indian", "indian", "flag", "bull", "bully", "bullshit"]

Result = sorted([ (sum([ w.startswith(prefix) for w in words ]) , prefix )  for prefix in words])[::-1]
```

it goes through every word as a prefix and checks how many of the other words start with it and then sorts the result. the[::-1] simply reverses that order

Answer (score 0):

If we know the length of the prefix (say 3)

```
from nltk import FreqDist
suffixDist=FreqDist()
for word in vocabulary:
    suffixDist[word[-3:]] +=1
commonSuffix=[suffix for (suffix,count) in suffixDist.most_common(150) ]
print(commonSuffix)
```